VIF for interaction terms in moderated mediation analysis
In my understanding, the VIF can be naturally inflated for interaction terms based on being a product of two independent variables?
I would like to read up on multicollinearity for models including interactions, is there some literature available that I could also potentially cite?

The seminal works on collinearity are the books by Belsley. 1) Regression Diagnostics: Identifying Influential Data and Sources of Collinearity  and Conditioning Diagnostics: Collinearity and Weak Data in Regression. Both cover interactions, but both recommend condition indexes rather than VIF.
The usual way of dealing with interactions is to center the variables at 0 before multiplying them. Whether this gets rid of the collinearity or not is controversial (or, at least, it was the last time I looked at the literature) but it will reduce the VIF (and the condition indexes).
Also, see this thread
